# I need to create/remove the contact groups?

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, office365

I need to create/remove the contact groups *( Distribution Lists )* in exchange server. How can i do that.?

When i googled about `Distribution Lists` there are three types of Distribution Lists

a) Universal Distribution Groups

b) Security Groups

c) Contact Groups

By using New-DistributionGroup we can create only Universal or Security type distribution groups. But for Contact Groups how can i create them? Also i need to remove the created Contact Group as well. If anybody have idea on it please send reply.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Universal Distribution Groups and MailEnabled Security Groups are Active Directory objects, Unified Groups where introduced recently in Office365 http://windowsitpro.com/office-365/using-office-365-groups-outlook-2016 which are different again, Contact Groups are Exchange Store Objects the exists in Contacts folder in a Mailbox (or Public Folder) so you need to use a Mailbox API either MAPI via (Outlook OOM,Redemption etc) or EWS. To Create/Delete Contact groups in EWS you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn629394(v=exchg.150).aspx

If your looking of a powershell sample for doing this with EWS I have module on GitHub that can do this https://github.com/gscales/Powershell-Scripts/tree/master/EWSContacts

eg Create a ContactGroup in Mailbox

Create-ContactGroup  -Mailboxname mailbox@domain.com -GroupName GroupName -Members ("member1@domain.com","member2@domain.com")

Add more members to the Group

$Group = Get-ContactGroup -Mailboxname mailbox@domain.com -GroupName GroupName
$Group.Members.Add("newMember@domain.com")
$Group.Update(0)

Delete the Group

$Group = Get-ContactGroup -Mailboxname mailbox@domain.com -GroupName GroupName
$Group.Delete(2)

Cheers
Glen